# Is there a StackExchange client for Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, stack-exchange

In playing around with Windows 8, I find that it would be nice to have a dedicated app for it in the 'metro' interface.

Must:

- Have access to all sites
- Be able to read questions and answers
- View votes, revisions, etc.
- View user profiles (including badges and reputation and posts)

Nice to have

- Ability to post questions, answers and comments
- Ability to vote
- Ability to perform moderation actions like flagging, closing, etc.

Does such an app exist?

Comment: @Undo, Why will you prefer a metro app compared to a easy-open-easy-close webapp in the browser?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[You're not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5943/a-desktop-app-for-the-se-family) [the first](https://stackapps.com/questions/4481/native-windows-client-for-stack-exchange-sites) [person](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63687/is-there-a-client-tool-available-for-stack-overflow)
[to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79162/any-desktop-client-for-stack-overflow)
[this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134190/will-there-ever-be-a-read-write-desktop-client).

If there was one it would probably be posted on [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/). That being said a quick search under the [Windows](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag pulls up only about five results, none of which appear to be a full client like you are asking for.

There have been projects in the past such as [open-so-frontend](https://code.google.com/p/open-so-frontend/), which was last updated Sep 6, 2012 and probably doesn't work anymore.

The reason for this would appear to be that the Stack Exchange API has proven to be rather write inflexible. Please forgive me if I'm wrong, but it would seem as of [version 2.1](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/09/stack-exchange-api-v2-1/) the only [write capabilities](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write) the API contains are the creation and deletion of comments.

I'm sorry to say a desktop app does not exist at this time.

Comment: Actually, 2.2 exists. It's not public yet, but it does work. So you're right as of now.

Comment: @Undo, Does it allow to write questions and answers?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, version 2.2 of the API does. It was released some time ago, you can see the documentation for it [here](http://api.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Undo, Looks like there's still no way to register a "test API" even in 2.2